# Converting date/time string into datetime object - format does not match

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert the string:

```
'2018-10-16T11:41:39.29166592Z'
```

Into a datetime object using strptime. It seems the string format is wrong.

Running the line below:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-10-16T11:41:39.29166592Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
```

outputs:

> ValueError: time data '2018-10-16T11:41:39.29166592Z' does not match
>   format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'

Using the format: `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%9fZ'` doesn't work neither.

Thanks

Comment: as You can read in documentation "When used with the `strptime()` method, the `%f` directive accepts from **one to six digits** and zero pads on the right.". So you have string with too precise format.

Comment: for more precise solutions check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207365/working-with-high-precision-timestamps-in-python

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `dateparser` module.

**Ex:**

```
import dateparser
print(dateparser.parse('2018-10-16T11:41:39.29166592Z'))
```

**Output:**

```
2018-10-16 11:41:39.291665+00:00
```

**[MoreInfo](https://pypi.org/project/dateparser/)**

---

Or `dateutil`

**Ex:**

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
print(parse('2018-10-16T11:41:39.29166592Z'))
```

**[MoreInfo](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)**